# routing.yml import when using FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, fosrestbundle

I follow tutorial in here (http://npmasters.com/2012/11/25/Symfony2-Rest-FOSRestBundle.html) about using FOSRestBundle.

When setting up the route, I get error :

```
Cannot import resource "D:\xampp\htdocs\SymRestTestApp\src\Per\RestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" from "D:/xampp/htdocs/SymRestTestApp/app/config\routing.yml".
```

My app/config/routing.yml

```
per_rest:
    resource: "@PerRestBundle/Controller"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /

per:
    type: rest
    resource: "@PerRestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

My Per/RestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:

```
organisation:
    type: rest
    resource: Per\RestBundle\Controller\OrganisationController

user:
    type: rest
    parent: organisation
    resource: Per\RestBundle\Controller\UserController
```

Anyone experience this issue? How to fixed this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pushed a commit to the repository which should fix this issue. See: https://github.com/nmpolo/Symfony2Rest/commit/d381b0a4652e76d5a4c1576d1afd8fa0e00eb0c1

This was being caused because the FOSRestBundle now requires you to implement ClassResourceInterface in your controllers to use implicit routing. See: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md#implicit-resource-name-definition

Comment: Yup, I'm missing the ClassResourceInterface

Comment: The link to the documentation is broken

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas Janel. The documentation has moved here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#implicit-resource-name-definition